# lasso and cross-validation (theoretical results)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, cross-validation, lasso

is there any theoretical result which says that use the minimum of the cross-validation as value for the lasso penalty is a good choice?

I would like something like $P(S_0 \subset \hat S_{lasso}(\lambda_{cv}))\rightarrow 1$ where $S_0$ is the set of true variable.

Where can I find it?

Comment: This is a pretty generic question about generalization error and empirical risk minimization.

Comment: In the book statistics for high dimensional data they said :" The empirical fact that often $S_0\subset \hat S$ 
is supported by theory. " Where can I found that theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property that you're looking for is sometimes called the "oracle property": Can we estimate the true subset $S_0$ of variables with increasing number of observations $n$?

It has been shown that the classical lasso has the oracle property only under some specific conditions (see [here](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~zouxx019/Papers/adalasso.pdf)).

My best guess is that these conditions transfer to the case of the lasso with cross-validation.